# Código retornando "-nan"

Tags: c, array

Fiz um código que executa 2 funções:

1. calcula a média de salários de uma empresa
2. calcula a diferença do salário de cada empregado para a média salarial

Quando executo, dá um erro no retorno da função 2 (`exibeDifMedia`), pois aparece o `"-nan"`.
Quando eu faço o mesmo cálculo que está na função direto na `main`, ele exibe o valor correto. Creio que seja algum problema na construção da função, porém não estou conseguindo encontrar.

Alguém para me dar uma luz?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

float calcMedia(float vet[], int tam) {
    float media, soma = 0;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<tam; i++) {
        soma = soma + vet[i];
    }
    
    media = (float)soma/tam;
    
    return media;
}

float exibeDifMedia (int vInsc[], float vSal[], int num) {
    float difmedia, mediasal;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
      
        difmedia = mediasal - vSal[i];
            
    }

    return difmedia;
}

int main(void){
    int vInsc[6] = {1010,1020,1030,1040,1050,1060};
    float vSal[6] = {1000.00,4020.00,900.00,10400.00,20000.00,1000.00};
    float mediasal, difsal;
    int i;
    
    mediasal = calcMedia(vSal, 6);
    printf("A media dos salários é de %.2f\n", mediasal);

    for (i = 0 ; i <= 5; i++) {

        printf("\nsalário do funcionário [%d] = %.1f\n",vInsc[i], vSal[i]);
        difsal = exibeDifMedia(vInsc, vSal, 6);
        printf("\nDiferença de salário do funcionário [%d] para a média = %.1f\n",vInsc[i], difsal);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Na função `exibeDifMedia` você utiliza a variável `mediasal` sem ter atribuído um valor a ela. Note também que seu cálculo está dentro de um loop e portanto você sobrescreve o valor calculado a cada ciclo e o retorno da função será o último valor calculado.

Comment: entendi! vou fazer as aletrações aqui! obrigada!